よう and ように nuances
I found an example - 家族に言わないようにお願いした. So, if I want to clarify who I'm asking, is it correct to say - (私は)彼に家族に言わないようにお願いした? I also saw an option when the person we are asking for something is at the end of the sentence, but "に" is removed from "ように". In that case, it would be like this - 家族言わないよう　(私は)彼にお願いした. Is that correct?

Actually, 彼に家族に言わないお願いした is incorrect. You cannot remove "ように" in this sentence. So, the correct form would be "彼に家族に言わないようにお願いした."
Although this sentence is grammatically correct, many people (even native speakers) may find it difficult to understand smoothly. A better sentence would be "家族に言わないよう彼にお願いした."
Now, let me explain why the first sentence needs improvement and why the seconds sentence is better. Let's compare the sentences.

彼に家族に言わないようにお願いした。 (this needs improvement)
家族に言わないよう彼にお願いした。 (This is better)

The first difference between the sentences is the placement of "彼に." It may seem trivial, but it's actually significant for clarity. Both sentences consist of a main clause and a subordinate clause. To clarify, I'll use "(sub-clause) symbols in both sentences.

彼に(sub-sentence)ようにお願いした。
(sub-sentence)よう彼にお願いした。

Now it's clear that in first sentence, the structure alternates between the main clause and the sub-clause, making it more complex. In contrast, the second sentence starts with the sub-clause and then moves to the main sentence, making it simpler.
"ように" and "よう" and indicate the end of a sub-clause. When a listener hear "よう," they understand that everything so far is a sub-clause and expect the main clause next. However, the first sentence is confusing because it mixes the main clause and sub-clause, forcing the listener to figure out which part belongs to which.
Another difference between the first and second sentences is the first one uses "ように," while the second uses "よう." You could use "ように" in the second sentence as follows:
家族に話さないように彼にお願いした。
In this case, you'll notice that "に" appears twice in the sentence. This is considered poor style because "てにおは" (particles) should ideally not appear more than once in close succession. Since "ように" and "よう" are interchangeable here,  it's better to use "よう" to avoid repetition.
Lastly, "家族言わないよう　(私は)彼にお願いした" is incorrect because you cannot omit "に" after "家族." The correct version is "家族に言わないよう　(私は)彼にお願いした."

Grammatically speaking, both (私は)彼に家族に言わないお願いした and 家族言わないよう　(私は)彼にお願いした are incorrect. The word 願う, or in this case it's honorary form お願いする, can only take the particle に or と. If you're wishing a NOUN, then you can say NOUNにお願いする, or, if your wish is stated in a CLAUSE, then you can say CLAUSEとお願いする.
In your example, 家族に言わない (don't tell the families) is the speaker's wish, so either make that into a noun with よう, then use に with お願いする, or use that clause "家族に言わない" as-is and use と.
The correct versions are:

家族に言わないようにお願いする

家族に言わないとお願いする


Not using と or nominalizing the clause with よう but not using に would make it grammatically incorrect.
As a side note, the お願いする can actually be omitted, and very often is, when making a wish, especially when the wish is in the form of XXように. For example, if I wanna say "I wish tomorrow is gonna be a beautiful day," it's more customary to say 明日が綺麗な日になりますように rather than 明日が綺麗な日になりますようにお願いします. Note how it's 丁寧語 before the ように (なります not なる), but technically 明日が綺麗な日になるように is also acceptable

got it, thanks. but if i want to add "asked "HIM" not to tell my family". where should i  add 彼, for example?

Could you give the complete English sentence?

"I asked Yamada not to tell my family"

Then this has nothing to do with 願う anymore, since the verb here is "I asked" not "I wish". That's a completely different sentence with a completely different verb. 山田に家族に言わないと頼んだ.
